# How to remove saved password from firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have to remove browser save password from firefox extension for my particular domain.
How can I ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This will remove all your custom settings and settings for many extensions.
Open your profile folder:

On the menu bar, click on the Help menu and select Troubleshooting Information. The Troubleshooting Information tab will open.

Under the Application Basics section, click on Show in Finder. A window with your profile folder will open.

On the menu bar, click on the Firefox menu and select Quit Firefox

Locate the prefs.js file (and, if present, the prefs.js.moztmp file).
Delete those files and any prefs-n.js files where n is a number (e.g. prefs-2.js).
Delete Invalidprefs.js if it exists.
Restart Firefox. You should now have all your preferences reset.

Based on information from Preferences not saved (mozillaZine KB)